# Formatting data from Firebase with HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, firebase-realtime-database

This time I'm facing a problem with formatting data from Firebase. This is how structure in my database looks:

[image]

I'm getting it from database using this code:

```
const preObject = document.getElementById('object')
var parametryObject = firebase.database()
    .ref('Parametry_powietrza')
    .limitToLast(1)
    .once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        var listaParametrow = snapshot.val();
        console.log(listaParametrow);
        preObject.innerText = JSON.stringify(snapshot.val(), null, 3)
    });
```

And on my webpage it looks like:

[image]

My question is - how to properly refer to that data to be able to change its appearance using HTML and CSS?

Thank you! :)

Comment: take a look here
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_html.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For-each over an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @yakirMalka It uses POST method and actually I'm not sure how to use it in my case, if my database is in Firebase. Isn't it intended to use with MySQL etc? Sorry for so trivial question, but I'm a total beginner :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to access the data inside your JSON object being returned to you from your FireBase RealTime database (RTDB). But the way you've structured your data makes it near impossible for your javascript to iterate through it.

Some pointers I can give you regarding your data in the Realtime Database atm:

1) Datetime is typically stored in what's called [Epoch Time](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/e/epoch.htm). Which is typically the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970. The number can easily be converted back into text using various javascript time libraries. An easy one to try out is [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/). You can see epoch time with this online convertor [here](https://www.epochconverter.com/).

2) Secondly, RTDB supports the creation of unique, sequential, sortable "push-id" whenever you call the `.push({ myDataObject })` function. So there's no need to store the date and the time as the "keys" to your object. More info about the push-id [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data) and [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html). It's really interesting stuff!

3) I hate to be writing this suggestion because it seems like taking a step back before you can take steps forward, but I feel like you would benefit alot on looking at some articles on designing databases and how to sensibly structure your data. Firebase also has a great introduction [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/structure-data). If it's any help, for your data structure, I suggest modifying your data structure to something like below:

```
{
  Parametry_powietrza: {
    [firebase_push_id]: {
      timestamp: 726354821,
      Cisnienie: 1007.78,
      Temperatura: 19.23,
      Wilgotnosc: 52.00,
    },
    [firebase_push_id]: {
      timestamp: 726354821,
      Cisnienie: 1007.78,
      Temperatura: 19.23,
      Wilgotnosc: 52.00,
    }
  }
}
```

That way, when firebase returns your data, you can iterate through the data much more easily and extract the information you need like:

```
database
  .ref('Parametry_powietrza')
  .limitToLast(10)
  .once('value', snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(child => {
      // do what you need to do with the data
      console.log("firebase push id", child.key);
      console.log("data", child.val());
    })
  });
```

All the best! BTW are you using any javascript frameworks like React or Vue?

Comment: Firebase also has a bunch of videos that teach you how best to structure your data here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data. It is for their other database product called Firestore but the concepts are the same. The API is just a little different.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that huge comment! I need some time to get through it and hyperlinks you've provided, hence probably I will disappear for some time :D
I'll let you know once resolve my problem or, what is more likely, I'll encounter any issues :D

PS. no, I'm not using any frameworks :)

Comment: No probs! I suppose if you really want to stick with vanilla javascript, inside the `.forEach(child)` you could call `document.getElementById('elementId').innerHTML = child.val()` but then you run into other complicated problems like needing to know the `elementId` you're going to be setting the innerHTML for... Take a look into a javascript framework if you have time. It's the way modern web is built. My recommendation is Vue because i feel it's more beginner friendly. It'll help you organise your code alot better :)